# PHP Gateway Login Management Systen

Tags: linux, php, lamp

Situation: Creating self hosted web services to share with friends on Linux machine. E.g. wiki, ownCloud, etc.

Problem: Every web service requires individual logins. Troublesome.

Question: Is there a pre existing framework that I can make use of to setup a gateway login system, i.e. I log in as ABC, I will show up as ABC on ALL hosted services.

Additional information: LAMP stack is being used here with most of my web applications. I also have a Windows server running in the same subnet.

Comment: Depends on solutions you use, you can setup LDAP server for authentication.

Comment: So if I have a generic login page that authenticates, as long as the appropriate flags are in place the log in will be persistent across services?

Comment: When you setup LDAP, that would be user database that will be queried by each service you wish to login. Login persistence across all services should be solved by yourself.

Comment: I see. You want to post that as an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Wiki page.

> A common use of LDAP is to provide a central place to store usernames and passwords. This allows many different applications and services to connect to the LDAP server to validate users.

We had local LDAP service which was storing all employees data.
Then we connected services like Jenkins, Email server etc. to LDAP server for AUTH.

In order to keep users logged in to all services you need to do some custom work.
That should not be much of a work, custom code should just login users to all services once it authenticates against LDAP server.